# Qubits are drawn multiple times in circuit using pennylane

Tags: pennylane

When I draw my circuits some qubits are drawn multiple times (see 'circuit 1'). Does this mean that 1) the circuit itself is the same as 'circuit 2' below or 2) do I have some bug in my code that causes this and my circuit is not equivalent to 'circuit 2'?

Circuit 1:

```
0: ──X───RZ(0.00)──SX──RZ(3.14)──SX──RZ(9.42)───────────╭X────┤ ╭<Z@Z@Z@Z>
1: ──SX──RZ(3.14)──SX──RZ(9.42)─╭X──────────────────────│─────┤ ├<Z@Z@Z@Z>
2: ──SX──RZ(3.14)──SX──RZ(9.42)─│───────────────────────│─────┤ ├<Z@Z@Z@Z>
3: ──X───RZ(0.00)──SX──RZ(3.14)─│────SX────────RZ(9.42)─│──╭X─┤ ╰<Z@Z@Z@Z>
2: ─────────────────────────────╰●──────────────────────│──╰●─┤           
1: ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────╰●────┤
```

Circuit 2:

```
0: ──X───RZ(0.00)──SX──RZ(3.14)──SX──RZ(9.42)───────────╭X───-─┤ ╭<Z@Z@Z@Z>
1: ──SX──RZ(3.14)──SX──RZ(9.42)─╭X──────────────────────╰●─────┤ ├<Z@Z@Z@Z>
2: ──SX──RZ(3.14)──SX──RZ(9.42)─╰●───────────────────────╭●────┤ ├<Z@Z@Z@Z>
3: ──X───RZ(0.00)──SX──RZ(3.14)─────SX────────RZ(9.42)───╰X─---┤ ╰<Z@Z@Z@Z>
```

Comment: Hi @qcabepsilon, are you able to share (a minimal non-working example of) your code? It looks like a bug, but would need to see code to verify what's happened

Comment: It was indeed a bug, which I did not recognize as one at first because no errors hinted at it.

Answer (score 1):

The two circuits are not equivalent and the reason for this behavior is a bug in my code, as co9olguy suggested. I found that `1`and `2` of the name of the second set of qubits were strings in contrast to the first set, that was named by integers.